# Unsure of German PhD salary

Tags: phd, salary, germany

I have been offered a phd position in Germany at 75% TVL-E13. It seems very difficult to get a precise figure for what this is in Euro. From a Google search I have figures for this position ranging from €21000 right up to €30000 on various websites dating back over the last couple of years.

I have a deadline on my decision so I really need to know what this 75% TVL-E13 rate amounts to in Euro at the moment so I can weigh it up against offers in other countries. Is this a 'good' rate for a PhD? Is anyone on this rate at present or does anyone have a good idea of how much this salary is currently worth in Euro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I live and work in Berlin since 6 years I don't understand much about these matters, but, while doing a PhD in Biology here (so 6 to 3 years ago) I was paid at a rate called "BAT IIa/2" which left me (once the taxes, the charges and the insurances were removed) with ca. €1100 a month to live.
Now a BAT IIa/2, as the name indicates, correspond to half a BAT IIa, which is [said](http://www.cats.rwth-aachen.de/jobs/bat) to have been replaced in the current scale by TVL-E13. From that I gather that a 75% TVL-E13 should end up leaving you with a "Netto" (i.e. tax-free, charge-free, insurance-free) salary of ca. €1650 per month.
And indeed according to the website http://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/tv-l/, it should end up in [this range](http://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/c/t/rechner/tv-l/berlin?id=tv-l-berlin&g=E_13&s=1&zv=VBL&z=75&zulage=&stj=2015&stkl=1&r=0&zkf=0&kk=15.5): i.e. an annual salary of ca. €31k (gross) / €20k (net).

The exact sum will change according to [many factors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/44699/9664), including in which region (Land) you end up in, etc.

Comment: It is in southern Germany, I don't know if that brings it up or down.

Comment: It should make it slightly higher than in Berlin: http://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/c/t/rechner/tv-l/west?id=tv-l&g=E_13&s=1&zv=VBL&z=75&zulage=&stj=2015&stkl=1&r=0&zkf=0&kk=15.5

Comment: Southern Germany...I believe it is €2610 a month base, I don't know how that corresponds to the figures you are using for the calculator.

Comment: It s still the same: southern and northern are both western, which is what matters in this case. Berlin is the lowest anyway. You have pretty good explanations on how to use that online calculator in this answer: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/44699/9664